# Restkit mapping multiple json feeds to the same array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I was wondering how i can get more than one request from different url to mappingResults.array

I have put all of the results into an array but when i run the request a second time i think that it overwrites with the new feed instead of adding it to my existing array.  Any ideas how i can do this, does it need to be a NSMutableArray, in which case how would i set it?

```
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {


   NSArray *weatherObjects = mappingResult.array;
```

This works here but only allows the array to hold 1 set of feeds from the api i am using?

Answer (score 0):

Change `weatherObjects` to be a mutable array. Create the instance before you make any requests and then add the mapping results to the mutable array.